# ASP.Net MVC - How should i do integration testing on an ASP.net MVC application without necessarily running all the tests via the browser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ASP.Net MVC - How should i do integration testing on an ASP.net MVC application without necessarily running all the tests via the browser?

Comment: More information please? Whats being integrated?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Visual Studio Web Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182538(VS.80).aspx) to record and execute a scenario. [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is another alternative.